# PL/SQL Replicating a table with a trigger on Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have never used triggers in PLSQL before, but I am now supposed to make a trigger that replicates the table of one database, and creates a copy of this table in another database. I am using AQT(Advanced Query Tool) as DBMS, and i have 2 database connections, and I need to copy the table and or data from DB1 to DB2. It's only based on one table that I need replicated, following tutorialspoint I have concluded that it should look somewhat like this:
`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER db_transfer
    AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON X
    WHEN (NEW.ID > 0)
```

I don't think i need for each since i want a copy of the whole table, and the condition is supposed to trigger this replication of the DB table. Is this the right approach?

### EDIT

For anyone who uses AQT, they have a feature under Create -> Trigger -> and then click on the relevant tables etc to create it.

Comment: Is there a connection between DB1 and DB2?

Comment: Please don't use answers to add information to a question. There's an `edit` button just below the tags - in the future, please edit your question to add information. I've copied the text from your answer to the question. Thanks.